# How to add multiple operations to NSOperation Queue?

Tags: iphone, codeblocks, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I want to parallelize certain code similar to following sample. I am trying to add 10 successive iterations of a loop to a block operation , the problem I am facing is only the 1st block is getting executed.

```
 NSMutableArray *arrayOfOps=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

`for (int i=0; i<totalCount()+10; i=i+10) {

    NSBlockOperation *op=[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

        for (int hh=i; (hh<=10)&(hh<totalCount); hh++) {


         //some code

        }


    }];

    [arrayOfOps addObject:op];


}


[OperationQueue addOperations:arrayOfOps waitUntilFinished:YES];

[arrayOfOps removeAllObjects];
[arrayOfOps release];`

Answer (score -1):

You are removing the operations from the array with "removeAllObjects" after submitting it to the operation queue. The operation queue probably just retains the array, rather than copying it, and therefore removing the operations influences how the queue behaves.

Just delete that line and you should be OK.

Comment: assumptions... assumptions... let's do some minimal research, shall we? __[here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operationqueue)__ it says: _"After being added to a queue, an operation remains in that queue until it is explicitly canceled or finishes executing its task."_

Comment: @holex if you had done even minimal research, you would have seen that the question and answer are 5 years old. Is that really worth your energy?

Comment: you can delete or update your obsolete answers anytime.